# Why VBA Runtime error 13 Type mismatch while starting DDE conversation

Tags: excel, vba, dde

I have this code:

```
Public channel As Long

Sub Button1_Click()
  MsgBox "all is OK"

  ' Application.ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
  channel = Application.DDEInitiate("Excel", "System")

  MsgBox "Conversation started"

End Sub
```

Why DDEInitiate expression gives error 13?

Comment: Are you aware that DDE is not secure? "Security  Dynamic data exchange (DDE) is an older technology that is not secure. If possible, use a more secure alternative to DDE, such as object linking and embedding (OLE)." from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171947(v%3Doffice.11)

Comment: For the sake of syntax, have you tried writing it out?   `channel = DDEInitiate(App:="Excel", Topic:="System")`  I'm not seeing how that should make a world of difference, considering it's the 2 arguements in the appropriate order... but worth a shot

Comment: "Once you’ve installed the December 2017 security updates for Office 2016, 2013, 2010 and 2007   DDE is disabled." see https://office-watch.com/2017/dde-finally-dead-took-microsoft-long/

Comment: If you try `DDEInitiate(vbNullString, vbNullString)`, you get a windows to select the DDE. You will see that Office apps won't work, while Folder for example still works.

Comment: @VincentG I've seen that, but putting a `2` in that `AllowDDE` value did not fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The registry keys shown in the office-watch blog mentioned by @VincentG were only relevant for Writer. Excel has its own set of keys (which one can check using Sysinternals ProcMon, both when Excel starts, and when DDEInitiate is called from VBA), which are at least:

- In `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options` - `DDEAllowed:REG_DWORD=1`
- In `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security` - `DisableDDEServerLaunch:REG_DWORD=0`, `DisableDDEServerLookup:REG_DWORD=0`.

I didn't check which of them are the minimum requirement. Anyway, indeed, enabling DDE would be a security risk.